# Error Creating Standard Object Quote Instance in Apex

Tags: apex, controller, salesforce1-app, error-messages, quote

I want to create quote instance in custom controller but its giving me an error

```
Quote q = new Quote();
q.Name = 'quote'; // error variable does not exist: Name
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't think this code would give you this error. Can you copy and paste the code you're having trouble with?

Comment: Silly question: Do you have a custom class named Quote? That would totally muck things up. Try changing the code to: `Schema.Quote q = new Schema.Quote(); q.Name = 'quote';`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure as I haven't checked, but I'm pretty sure Quotes will use an autonumber field so you won't be able to set the name like this.

Comment: Did you enabled quotes for your org .

Comment: i have checked name is string type

Answer (score 0):

I've run your code in 'execute anonymous' mode in the dev console and it passes ok. If quotes wasn't activated you'd get 'entity is not org-accessible.

If you run the code in dev console do you get the same error as in your controller?